# Invoking with textbox c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, event-handling, serial-port

Part of my program uses an event handler for the receive data of my serial port. The idea is when data is received that the text received is then added to the textbox (rx). I did not used to have this problem but something has changed and I can't figure out what. So now I am re-examining the way this is handled.

During the form load of my winform the last thing I do is

```
if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
{
     serialPort1.Open();
     serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
}
```

Then I have the event handler

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
     string indata1 = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
    // rx.Text = " "; accidentally posted this. it was from trial and error.  
     rx.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + indata1);
}
```

When I run the program it stops at the `rx.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + indata1);` and gives the error

> invalidoperationexception was unhandled: Control "accessed from a
>   thread other than the thread it was created on.

From what I have been able to read suggests that I need to use `invoke` or `BeginInvoke`.

I have never had problems appending the text before so now I can't understand why it's a problem. Also from what I have been reading on invoking i just don't understand it.

Can someone help me understand how to use the invoke instance for my situation? or perhaps show me another way of appending the text box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually the exception you're seeing occurs when you run in debug mode, and if you run your application in release mode, you're unlikely to see the exception.

However, it is best to use invoke, as you have read.  Something like this:

```
    private delegate void RefreshTextBox();

    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
        //this event is raised in an event separate from UI thread, 
        //so InvokeRequired must be checked and Invoke called to update UI controls. 
        if (this.InvokeRequired) {
            RefreshTextBox d = new RefreshTextBox(RefreshTextBoxResults);
            Invoke(d);
        } else {
            RefreshTextBoxResults();
        }
    }

    private void RefreshTextBoxResults() {
        string indata1 = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
        rx.Text = " ";
        rx.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + indata1);
    }
```

The first time you see this invoke stuff, it's nearly impossible to follow, but take a close look and give it some time and it will make sense.  Promise. :)

Comment: So this makes sense then. I am actually running the application on a different computer. So when I make a release and take it to that machine it worked. I only recently brought the serial device to the development computer because I got lazy and tired of walking back and forth.

Thank you for pointing that out. I had not considered that I was only seeing a problem because VS is running.

Comment: @eatumup: Don't think that if the error does not appear the problem is not there. There is still a concurrency bug lurking when you try to update the GUI from the wrong thread.

Comment: @Tudor, any idea why the bug doesn't present in release mode?  You're definitely correct, just curious as to why it plays nice in release vs debug.

Comment: @Grant H.: I guess it's because Release is more geared towards efficiency, so they probably wanted to avoid throwing another exception (which is time-consuming) and freezing the app. Unfortunately the results are much more confusing if you're not very experienced. I saw many people simply concluding that the debugger was the problem. :)

Comment: From the msdn documentation:  The .NET Framework helps you detect when you are accessing your controls in a manner that is not thread safe. When you are running your application in the debugger, and a thread other than the one which created a control attempts to call that control, the debugger raises an InvalidOperationException with the message, "Control control name accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

This exception occurs reliably during debugging and, under some circumstances, at run time. You are strongly advised to fix this problem when you see it.

Comment: I definitely should not have just trusted that the error checker got everything. I should have checked it in debugging mode. I think that would have saved me a lot of confusion before figuring out that I needed to look at invoking. @hmqcnoesy Will your example clear the textbox or just add to it? I messes up with my sample and forgot to delete a line that clears it.

Comment: This works as well. I wish I could select two answers. Although longer than the example given by Tudor, I think this one is simpler for me to understand its process.

Comment: I copied your code and pasted it into the body of the `RefreshTextBoxResults()` method.  So hopefully you can recognize what's going on there and adjust as needed.

Answer (score 6):

Updates in GUI applications should only be done on the GUI thread. Another thread attempting to update GUI components directly will result in either the error you described or in seemingly random behavior.

The role of `Invoke` & friends is to enable a secondary thread to safely forward GUI updates to the GUI thread, which will then process them from a queue.

In your case (assuming WinForms here):

```
rx.BeginInvoke(
      (Action)(() =>
      {
          rx.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + indata1);
      }));
```

`BeginInvoke` is asynchronous, so the thread calling it will not wait for the actual updates to be processed before moving on, while `Invoke` is synchronous.

Comment: This has helped me a bit I think in my understanding. However when I add your snippet the error checker does not like the ') =>'. So I am still a little puzzled. And I also messed up. the rx.text = " "; was supposed to be removed. That was leftover from trial and error.

Comment: @eatumup: Which version of .net are you using?

Comment: My application is set for target framework 4. It's also a WinForm under Visual Studio 2010

Comment: @eatumup: Sorry about that. I missed a couple of parenthesis. It should compile fine now.

Comment: Thanks for that. To be honest I feel silly. I should have caught that. Your right though. It makes it work great. I think I am about 75% there in understanding the logic in how the BeginInvoke function is laid out. I just need to spend a little more time looking at it closer. I like how concise it is too. Thanks again.